# Telegram API - Create Chat Public Link

Tags: android, telegram

I am building an android app using the telegram api. I used the prebuilt library for android

The user needs a public facing channel so I can forward messages through a non telegram interface So first I call this method

```
 telegramClient.send(new TdApi.CreateNewSupergroupChat(chanName, true, chanDesc, null)  , handler);
```

Now I need to convert this to a public channel with an invite link so that I can forward messages

which api method does this?

When getting the message link I see the api method GetMessageLink() or getmessageembedingcode

If you know of a forum where I can ask this and get a better response please advise and I will delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set a line break and read a random chats fields and compare them to the link provided in the app so I knew which field needed to be set. The field was username. Once set the supergroup would be public

Then I had to use the regex search to find the api method knowing it had to involve the words username, supergroup, chat, link etc followed by the class it extended named function

This search found it

supergroup.*function

TdApi.SetSupergroupUsername()